# Java casting (dynamic)

Tags: java, exception, casting

I'm sure this is a very stupid question, but still I would like to know, is it possible to cast the global variable `cause` dynamically, in other words without using the `instanceof` operator ?

The reason for this question is, I feel the `instanceof` operator is not doing anything great here, it's just casting the `cause` statically, but in either case it's creating a `new IOException(cause)`

Because the `cause` is of type `Object`, I had to type cast it to either `String` or `Throwable`.

```
private Object cause; // global variable
//...
if (failed)
    throw cause instanceof String ? new IOException((String) cause) : new IOException((Throwable) cause);
```

Below is the actual code snippet where the two overridden methods will be called asynchronously.

```
public class Command implements ResponseListener {
    private Object cause;

    // ...
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String message, String status) {
        // ...
        if (!status.equals(MyConstants.COMPLD_MSG)) {
            this.cause = status + " received for " + command.split(":")[0] + message;
            this.failed = true;
        }
        doNotify();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
        this.failed = true;
        doNotify();
    }

    public void waitForResponse(int cmdTimeout) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // ...
        if (failed)
            throw cause instanceof String ? new IOException((String) cause) : new IOException((Throwable) cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: instanceof is definetelly not for casting. It's unclear what you question is, looks like XY problem to me. Please, try to be more specific. In case you were thinking what XY problem is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I suppose you could use some reading on method overloading. That code is actually somewhat reasonable, because different constructors will be invoked based on the type of `cause`.

Comment: "Because the cause is of type Object". It is or it **needs** to be? Do you need to make any distinctions in the first place?

Comment: thank you all for your responses, I've added a code snippet for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not having always a **Throwable** for your *cause* variable ? **Throwable** seems more adapted to express a failure than a String. Plus it avoids you to use the "ugly" operator *instanceof*.

```
public class Command implements ResponseListener {
    private Throwable cause;

    // ...
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String message, String status) {
        // ...
        if (!status.equals(MyConstants.COMPLD_MSG)) {
            this.cause = new Throwable(status + " received for " + command.split(":")[0] + message);
            this.failed = true;
        }
        doNotify();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
        this.failed = true;
        doNotify();
    }

    public void waitForResponse(int cmdTimeout) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // ...
        if (failed)
            throw new IOException(cause);
    }
}
```

---

Update after discussion below:

```
public class Command implements ResponseListener {
    private String cause;

    // ...
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String message, String status) {
        // ...
        if (!status.equals(MyConstants.COMPLD_MSG)) {
            this.cause = status + " received for " + command.split(":")[0] + message;
            this.failed = true;
        }
        doNotify();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(Throwable cause) {
        if(cause.getMessage().isEmpty()) {
            this.cause = cause.toString();
        }
        else {
            this.cause = cause.getMessage();
        }
        this.failed = true;
        doNotify();
    }

    public void waitForResponse(int cmdTimeout) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // ...
        if (failed)
            throw new IOException(cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks @Spotted. That was my previous design, though instead of new Throwable(...) I was using new IOException(...), but it's getting wrapped up in another IOException because of the last line, which I feel is wrong, as while printing Stack Trace it was printing IOException Caused by: IOException

Comment: @surz you're right. What about simply throwing _cause_ ? `if (failed) throw cause;`

Comment: Now that's a good question. This code is at the middle layer, and I'm restricting propagation of any 3rd party Exceptions to UI layer. And in some cases these 3rd party Exceptions do not contain any message, in which case the wrapping up to IOException does the trick, to generate a **Caused by:** string

Comment: Not sure I correctly understood your last message.
What are the 3rd party exceptions you mention ? The **Throwable** you get in the _exceptionCaught_ callback ?
If so and you don't want to propagate any stacktrace, change the type of _cause_ to String: `private String cause;` and in _exceptionCaught_: `this.cause = cause.getMessage();`. Then you could return _cause_ wrapped in an IOException.

Comment: you're right! I'm using 3rd party JARs which generate the callbacks. This is a good idea to change `cause` to String and in exceptionCaught I can put another check for empty message, if empty then `this.cause = cause.toString();`

Comment: Why do you want to check for an empty message ? Don't you want to assign `getMessage()` to `cause` whatever its content is ? 

What will you do if the message is empty ? Letting `cause` be `null` and risking an NPE later ?

Comment: Actually the UI has as Table which has a Status and Reason column. The reason column is `cause.getMessage();`, if Status is **Failure** (if there's an exception) then there must be a Reason. If the exception contains no message Reason column will be blank, which will confuse the user (failure without any reason). The toString() will print the exception name at least. Yes, of course I've to check for null as well.

Comment: Seems like a flaw of your 3rd party library when returning an empty exception, but it's not your fault... :-) Checking for empty thus seems an acceptable workaround.
I also updated my answer following our discussion.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no common superclass of `String` and `Throwable` that would be acceptable as parameter to `IOException`, you have to cast it to one or the other, and in order to determine what to cast it to, you have to use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

[Class.cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Class.isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) methods may be used as dynamic counterparts of cast and `instanceof` operators respectively.